# How to structure the project folders of my application's service layer?

Tags: project-structure, namespace

I want to know how to structure my Service Layer

I have thought about something like that:

- Assembly called `SomeNamespace.Service`.
- Have a seperate folder for each problem domain (`SomeNamespace.Service.Email`).
- Structure by Interface/Model/Service

But then I am not sure, how to call the folder where the actual service is in:

```
SomeNamespace.Service.Email.Contract     <-- Interfaces/Abstract
- IEmailService
- ...

SomeNamespace.Service.Email.Model        <-- DTO/ValueObjects
- SmtpConfiguration
- MailMessage
- ...

SomeNamespace.Service.Email.???          <-- Actual Services, but Service again would sound bad
- EmailService
- ...
```

Is this project structure acceptable? Or are there better alternatives I should consider?

Comment: The Service Layer has nothing to say about your folder structure.  You can make that look any way you want.

Comment: If it's only about the folder name, what about "Implementation" or "Component" ?

Comment: Doesn't matter. For instance, in Java we use *.impl. Among other things, the namespace of your packages (folders) should help other devs to locate components. If EmailService is implementing IEmailService, it would make sense to call the folder "Implementation". As developer, I don't know what I expect to find inside a folder named "Components"